# How yo set/update data attribute with Kendo?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I expect to update 'data_company_id' with CellAction. But I have no any change. data_company_id stay always 'test' value. Where I making mistake?

```
  @(Html.Kendo().DefaultOverviewGrid<SmartFacqt.Web.Models.ComponentViewModel>()
                .Name("Grid")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(p => p.Code).HtmlAttributes(new { data_company_id = "test" });
                })
                          .CellAction(cell =>
                            {
                                cell.HtmlAttributes["data_company_id"] = "hhhhhhhhhhh";
                            })
                        .Events(events => events.DataBound("disableButtons"))
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Read(read => read.Action("Components_Read", "Component"))
                        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
                    )
            )
```

Comment: Are you saying it's setting the value to "hhhhh..." or not even that?

Comment: Not event that. I want that, I want set value to 'hhhhh...'. In my HTML, all values are 'test'.

Comment: Instead of `data_company_id` try `data-company-id`; I don't think the underscores are valid.

Comment: Not working. I used underscore because of this: http://www.telerik.com/forums/creating-data-bound-html-attributes-in-mvc-grid-cells .But not working even without underscore

Comment: The link you posted seems to assume that the grid is server bound, not ajax bound. It seems that CellAction does not work with Ajax binding.